# Madza scrum but has k6 engine suzuki 3piston

Tags: noise, mazda, camshaft, valve-train, scrum

Top cam shaft and cam cups shaking and seem need new ones but is there any chance to repair existing ones?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!